# Are the XLIFF translation files (I18n) in Symfony case-sensitive?

Tags: symfony1, internationalization, translation

Had a quick doubt...
Are the XLIFF translation files (used by I18n Helper) in Symfony case-sensitive?
Will __('Hi') & __('hi') both fetch different results?
What if the XML only has a hi?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are case-sensitive...
Some googling helped... http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/74581/

Is there a way to use the case-insensitive translation if the exact is not found?
so __('Hi') will use 'hi' when 'Hi' is not found :)

Comment: You could modify the `__()` function to do the extra `strtolower($string)` call in case of no match...